# How can I implement IDv3 tags in a Qt Program?

Tags: c++, qt, audio-player, id3

I just made a qt sound player, it can plays mp3 and other types of audio, but I want to make it more useful for reading the tracks name and maybe the text of the song, in a short future. For now the application only displays the name of the file.

What library should be implemented? I found some libraries but they are dated and no more supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different libraries for reading information on sound files, you can try [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/)

The code is easy to read if you are okaysh with C++:

```
#include <id3/tag.h>
```

First you need to know what are the possible informatio that the library can give to you:

```
void ShowKnownFrameInfo() {
     ID3_FrameInfo myFrameInfo;
    for (int cur = ID3FID_NOFRAME+1; cur < myFrameInfo.MaxFrameID(); cur ++)
    { 
     cout << "Short ID: " << myFrameInfo.ShortName(ID3_FrameID(cur)) <<
         " Long ID: " << myFrameInfo.LongName(ID3_FrameID(cur)) <<
         " Desription: " << myFrameInfo.Description(ID3_FrameID(cur)) << endl;
    }
 }
```

Use that information in the code below to access the information and use it anywhere

```
void readTags(const std::string& musicFile) {
    ID3_Tag myTag(musicFile);
    QScopedPtr<ID3_Tag::Iterator> iter(myTag.CreateIterator());
    ID3_Frame* myFrame = NULL;
    while (NULL != (myFrame = iter->GetNext()))
    {
        myFrame->Get("Key", 1024);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't ID3 reader in Qt. You can try [it](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/).